# Where can I find a proof of the Hasse norm theorem (in english)?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, brauer-group

I am interested in determining the Brauer group of $\mathbb{Q}$. A while ago I started reading about central simple algebras and Brauer groups. Till now I have proved up to the $B(K^{unr})=\mathbb{Z}/1\mathbb{Z}$ and thus the Hasse invariant isomorphism $B(K)=\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ for $K$ a local field of characteristic 0. I got stuck trying to make progress after realising that the injectivity of the $B(K) \rightarrow \oplus_{v \in M_K} B(K_v)$ is equivalent to the Hasse Norm theorem for prime degree, so I started looking up proofs, but the proofs by Hasse or Furtwangler I found online were in German so I couldn't understand them. So are there any proofs of the Hasse norm theorem in English available online?

Edit: Ok never mind, I found a proof in the MIT OCW. Thanks for the suggestions in the below comment

Comment: The Hasse norm theorem is proved in books that develop class field theory, so look for such books (online or offline). Pierce's book *Associative Algebras* describes Brauer groups of number  fields in section 18.5. At the start of section 18.4, he states the Hasse norm theorem and writes "all proofs of the norm theorem are long".  He uses the norm theorem and refers the reader elsewhere for a proof: Tate's article in Cassels and Froehlich, the Artin-Tate notes on CFT, and the algebraic number theory books by Janusz and by Lang.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Self-answering (should have done a bit ago) as the question served its purpose quite a bit ago:

A proof is available in Class Field Theory notes by James Milne. The same proof is also explained in the Lecture 23, MIT OCW, 18.786 Number Theory II.